# Python, MySQL, Django: set default value for table columns

Tags: python, mysql, django

My tables are specified as models in Python, which are then made into MySQL tables by Django. In Python:

```
class my_table(models.Model):
    is_correct = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

If I do an insert into this table then I want it to automatically insert 0 for the column `is_correct` unless I specify a different value. I also want this to happen if I am using raw sql or if I am inserting from a MySQL stored procedure.

The `default` argument only seems to work from within Python. It's not translated into anything that MySQL sees. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: This seems to be a problem that the Django project has decided to classify as [wontfix](http://osdir.com/ml/DjangoUsers/2009-03/msg01271.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `default` argument works on django level. If you want to move it to `mysql`, perform `ALTER TABLE ...` query manually.

You also can try to extend `models.IntegerField` and [override](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_type) `db_type`. But it should be done for every field...